# Deleting clones of a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making this "game" where an object is being shown and you can later create clones of the prefab or delete them. I have this script so far

```
public class globalControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabInstance;
    GameObject prefabInstanceClone;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("c"))
        {
            prefabInstanceClone = Instantiate(prefabInstance, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
                Destroy(prefabInstanceClone);
        }
    }

}
```

For making the clones, I'm using

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("c"))
   {
     prefabInstanceClone = Instantiate(prefabInstance, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

    }
```

And for deleting

```
 if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
    {
      Destroy(prefabInstanceClone);
    }
```

I have no problems with cloning the prefab I have, but when I try to delete the clones, I can only delete the last one created and I need to be able to delete all the clones I have.

Comment: declare a `List<GameObject>` and use it to add and remove the instantiated clones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public GameObject prefabInstance;
List<Object> prefabInstanceClones = new List<Object>();

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("c"))
    {
        prefabInstanceClones.Add(Instantiate(prefabInstance, transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
    {
        var last = prefabInstanceClones.LastOrDefault();
        prefabInstanceClones.Remove(last);
        Destroy(last);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class globalControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabInstance;
    GameObject prefabInstanceClone;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("c"))
        {
            prefabInstanceClone = Instantiate(prefabInstance, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
           foreach (var objects in prefabInstanceClone)
            {
            Destroy(objects );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question